# Lose external space on external HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive

I accidentally restored windows image into one drive of my external hard disk using Ghost 1.5 CD. Now that one drive of my external hdd is full, all of the window files and the free space size and total space size are also the same as Drive C: including the drive label in image that I restored, but the total space of that drive is only 50 GB in total while my actual space drive is 100 GB in total; it lost almost 50GB. All my previous files on drive are also lost as well. When I checked in Disk management, I saw its total space 100 GB at the bottom panel but show up only 50GB on the upper panel. and if I chose format it also can see 100GB of capacity.

I don't want to format it as I have many important files many years ago, and I think those files are hidden including my external space.

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try PhotoRec and it might be able to recover files from the unused areas where no other files existed.  However, I am not aware of any software available to the average person that can recover overwritten files.  You call a data recovery specialist like DriveSavers and ask them if they can do it, but don't expect it to be cheap.